# Wireless In Ear Monitoring System

Tags: audio, earphones

I am looking for an in ear monitoring system for the stage.
I don't have the money for the high end products, but I want at least decent quality. My limit is 500€.

I am a singer and prospective guitar player in my band, and on stage I want to have an in ear monitoring system.
I chose two systems:

LD Systems MEI 1000 G2 + Shure SE215CL

or

Shure PSM-200 with Shure SE112 Headhphones

Both seem to fulfill my requirements, which are:

- wireless
- two inputs, one for my microphone and one for future requirements
- decent headphones (?)
- correct frequencies (I live in germany)

I am not really sure which combination to use. The LD Systems solution is cheaper, so I would be able to use better headphones. In the solution from Shure it is in summary more expensive but I have only the SE112 Headphones, because they are contained as a set.

The things that matter to me are

- interference free transmission and no/ low latency monitoring
- good isolation of the headphones and enough volume (metal band... pretty loud sometimes...)
- decent sound quality (I don't mind some static noise, but I should be able to recognize what I hear)
- durability of equipment

So, what would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I chose the combination of LD MEI 1000 and Shure SE215CL.
The Shure device had no relevant features which would justify the price and the better headphones were a really good investment.

Tested and evaluated as good.